# Blocked scripts due to MIME type according to the console

Tags: html, static, mime-types, blocked

I have been having some issues after hosting my django website on render.com..  a section of my website doesn't style properly and I when I checked my console, I found that the browser is blocking some of my scripts (js and css) hence the abnormal display...  It's a **MIME type error**..  but it **works perfectly okay in local server/development**.

The error states - *The resource from “https://alleron.onrender.com/static/landing/plugins/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”)*.

Also only a section of my website is affected which is the landing pages.. User dashboard and admin panel works just fine since they use a separate template. Anyone encountered this issue before or knows the solution?  Here is the link to my website: https://alleron.onrender.com

Also to be more detailed, I have external APIs and I-frames like Google translator and crypto price frames.  It's also a Django website.

I've tried using a type attribute on my link and script tags.  Also checked my meta tags to be sure of no type="text/plain".  Also tried redeploying couple of times but issue persists

This is what the error looks like:
[console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWjZJ.jpg)

Please help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.